# Compiling and linking code to Scilab

Tags: scilab, xcos

I am working on C computational function for Scilab xcos block. When trying to compile and link the code to Scilab using `ilib_for_link('DO13','do13.c',[],"c")`, I get:

```
Generate a loader file
Generate a Makefile
Running the Makefile
Compilation of do13.c
Building shared library (be patient)

!------------- Compile file do13.c --------------             !
!                                                             !
!   IF NOT EXIST  Release mkdir Release                         !
!                                                             !
!   cl -D__MSC__ -DFORDLL -D_WIN64 -c -DSTRICT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_!
!     DEPRECATE -D__MAKEFILEVC__ -nologo -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB!
!     ~1.3/libs/MALLOC/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/mo!
!     dules/core/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/modules/!
!     api_scilab/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/modules/!
!     call_scilab/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/modules!
!     /output_stream/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/modu!
!     les/jvm/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/modules/loc!
!     alization/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/modules/d!
!     ynamic_link/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/modules!
!     /mexlib/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/modules/tim!
!     e/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/modules/windows_t!
!     ools/includes"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/libs/f2c"  -I"!
!     C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.3/libs/hashtable"  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/S!
!     CILAB~1.3/libs/intl" -W3 -Gd -Z7 -O2 -MT /Fo"Release/" /!
!     Fd"Release/" -DFORDLL do13.c                            !
!                                                             !
!do13.c                                                       !
!                                                             !
!


do13.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sci!
!     cos/scicos_block4.h': No such file or directory         !
!                                                             !
!NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft!
!      Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code !
!     '0x2'                                                   !
!                                                             !
!Stop.                                                        !
 !--error 10000 
ilib_compile: Error while executing Makelib.mak.
at line      76 of function ilib_compile called by :  
at line      90 of function ilib_for_link called by :
```

I am not expert in programming. What could these messages mean?

Comment: The error I'm able to extract out of this is: "Cannot open include file: 'sci! ! cos/scicos_block4.h': No such file or directory". You might want to check out wether the compiler is being pointed to the correct include directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just include scicos_block4.h instead of scicos/scicos_block4.h will fix the issue.